# Multiple Tables Sharing Info to one

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 4 tables, "Player", "Crafting", "Battling", "Gathering".
I made a relationship rule for Crafting, Battling and Gathering to share information to the Player table.

[image: Relationships]

The problem is that when I go to the player table it makes me choose which other table's information to display instead of showing all 3.

[image: Player Table]

[image: Players]

How can I make a relationship so that I can view all three other tables from the player table?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible and you don't need this. You already have all relationships you need. Just create a form based on Player table with 3 subforms and link them on form, no additional code required in simple case.

Also I would recommend do not use username as primary key, use Autonumber data type instead.